# Tiling problem : Number of ways a floor can be tiled

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Find number of ways a floor n meter length and 11 meter wide can be floored with tiles of 2 cm length and 1 cm wide wide tiles without breaking the tiles (assume n is even)

Could you please help in solving this?

Comment: Can the tiles be rotated? It seems rather trivial if not.

Comment: yes, it can be rotated.

Comment: We can help, but you should outline what you've tried and the context of the problem as it was posed to you.  Is there a similar problem you have already seen the solution for?

Comment: It is odd that you mention $n$ is even, since $n$ meters is $100n$ cm, the dimension you specified for the tiles.

Comment: yes hardmath , I got the point it is irrelevant.

Comment: I have thought of one approach. getting the first 3 arrangements, redefine the area and take further three more arrangements  and go on. in this way, a recursive program can solve this with caching of values to make it faster. I am a programer and it forces me to think this way. I am looking for a mathematical solution

Comment: The number is going to be big. If we restrict ourselves to solutions that consist of $2$ cm  x $2$ cm squares, then for a $1$ meter x $1$ meter area you have already $2^{2500}$ permutations. In reality you have even more....

Comment: yes, too hard for a recursive algorithm to handle. is there any mathematical approaches to address this problem in a different approach?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and start drawing different configurations.

Comment: Actually, you should start with much smaller areas, say $M$ cm x $N$ cm. Then count the number of permutations. Perhaps a pattern will arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimensions of the floor ($N$ meter x $11$ meter) are way too large compared to the size of the tiles ($2$ cm x $1$ cm). This corresponds to $N * 55000$ tiles. If we make the crude estimate that every tile can be either horizontally or vertically oriented, you get a number of the order of $2^{N*55000}$.

Clearly, the OP should reduce the dimensions of the floor by several orders of magnitude. In fact I would recommend to start with the smallest possible floors, say $M$ cm x $N$ cm. For these it is straightforward to explore the different patterns and to count their number. It is quite possible that a pattern emerges in the number of solutions as a function of $M$ and $N$.

For $M = 1$ there is only pattern possible: all tiles vertical.

For $M = 2$ we can derive the recurrence relation $n(M,N) = n(M,N-1) + n(M, N-2)$. With initial values $n(2,1) = 1$ and $n(2,2) = 2$. This results in a well-known Fibonacci series.

Comment: I will try this approach. The large number came in the context that I was trying to solve it programmatically and the large number made it impossible for a program to count the possibilities in a reasonable time

Comment: I am glad I could advice you. Good luck with your project.